# How to create a darken/lighten keyboard shortcut in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, illustrator-scripting, shortcuts, script

Searching for greyscale keyboard shortcuts I stumbled upon this [nice useful video](https://egghead.io/lessons/egghead-create-a-shortcut-to-quickly-check-greyscale-values-in-illustrator). However at minute 1:15 she uses a keyboard shortcut to quickly lighten and darken the selected colors. How does she do that?

She mentions that there's a previous video of hers explainig how to create such shortcut, but the video can't be found on her uploaded list.

I also found [this page](https://blog.darkwark.com/lightenDarken/) about a darken/lighten script, but the download link it's down.

So, how do you create such keyboard shortcut? I can't find anything about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a script to do this.

You could record an Action, and assign it to a function key, then increase the black by 10% using *Edit > Edit Colors > Adjust Colour balance*. Then record a similar second Action assigned to another function key, but this time to decrease the black by -10%.

An example

Here are two such Actions I recorded. One named "Colour-" and the other "Colour+". I assigned these to the F2 and F3 keys.

[image]

Here's an example showing darkening or lightening a colour by using these function keys.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. I expanded a bit on the shortcuts, and created four of them. Both options that increase +1/-1 and +10/-10 for the precise color hunting :)